# ANDROID nullpointer error while file creation

Tags: android, file, nullpointerexception

In the while statement, final2.add(read) is getting a nullpointer which leads me to believe that it is not reading the file correctly, so my question is the following am I obtaining the contents of the text file correctly?

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void loadOpp() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File y = new File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"Opponent.txt");
    FileReader x = new FileReader(y);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(x);
    String read;

    List<String> final2 = new ArrayList();               
    try {
        while((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            final2.add(read);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Spinner spinner= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, final2);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);        
}
```

logcat:

```
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.hoopstats/com.example.hoopstats.NewGame}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.hoopstats.NewGame.loadOpp(NewGame.java:67)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.example.hoopstats.NewGame.onCreate(NewGame.java:34)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-06 21:43:00.874: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: please indicate NewGame.java:67 and 34

Comment: the 67 was the line "spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);" and the 34 was the calling of the method loadOpp in the onCreate, so it is because of the same nullpointer in 67.

Comment: Have you done a simple check such as logging the value of `read` in each iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

See [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com)

In the question you state "final2.add(read)" is getting a null pointer, are you sure this is the case? That is not quite what the stack trace shows. I think the line

```
((read = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
```

ensures that this cannot be the case. This statement will be evaluated as follows

```
read = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

From the documentation, this returns "the contents of the line or null if no characters were read before the end of the reader has been reached."

```
(expression) != null
```

then the result of that expression is compared to null, so your code should never add null to final2.

I think it's more likely that your problem is with "findViewById" which may return null - again check the extensive online documentation. I would also remove the SuppressWarnings("null") attribute

It is possible that your code is wrong elsewhere. If in doubt add Log.d() throughout the method and see what comes up in logcat... Or debug that method... At a minimum log the lines that are being read, until you are sure your data has been correctly read.

This is how I think your code should read something like this (untested)...

```
public void loadOpp() {

    // Consider openFileInput(OPPONENT_FILE) instead of the following...
    File opponentFile = new File(getFilesDir(), OPPONENT_FILENAME);
    if (opponentFile.exists()) { // check the file exists
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(opponentFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        List<String> opponentList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            // Attempt some logging (exercise for the reader)
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), line);

            opponentList.add(line);
        }

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        if (spinner != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opponentList);
            dataAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Other things to check, does your file exist? Does it contain any data? Remember if you are creating a file, you should check whether there is available space on the device before creating the file... etc...

Hope that helps.